# OnDemandGrid not Loading in IE

Tags: dojo, dgrid

I am using OndemandGrid with JSONrest store.When hitting my xhtml page directly from IE ,the grid is not loading.I am getting script error as below

```
                      Line : 0
                      Char : 0
                      Error : Script Error
                      Code : 0
                      URL : http://localhost:8080/sample/dgridsample.xhtml
```

If I use ctlr+F5 Grid is loading.Below is my javascipt code

```
                        require([
        "dgrid/OnDemandGrid",
        "dojo/store/JsonRest",
        "dojo/dom",
        "dojo/dom-style",
        "dojo/_base/declare",
        "dgrid/extensions/ColumnResizer"
    ], function (OnDemandGrid,JsonRest,dom,domStyle,declare,ColumnResizer) {

            jsonstore = new JsonRest({target: url,idProperty: "srno"});
            grid = new(declare([OnDemandGrid,ColumnResizer]))({
                store: jsonstore,
                columns: Layout,
                minRowsPerPage : 40,
                maxRowsPerPage : 40,
                keepScrollPosition : true,
                loadingMessage: "Loading data...",
                noDataMessage: "No results found."
            }, "grid");
            domStyle.set(dom.byId("grid"),"height","230px");            
            grid.startup();
        });
```

When I put alert,I got undefined message box.

```
                  alert(grid); // getting undefined
                  domStyle.set(dom.byId("grid"),"height","230px");
```

Note : It works fine in Firefox.In IE ctrl+F5 loading the grid.
Can someone tell why it is not working in IE?

Comment: Have you tried running JSLint on the code?  Can you setup a jsfiddle to demonstrate it not working in IE.  Use this as a starting point: http://jsfiddle.net/WgaVg/7/